# using Fiddler with asp.net MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, fiddler

I want to use fiddler with asp.net MVC 3 application to see when I click on any link which action method is called and what is sent as request and what JSON comes back. Can someone suggest me good tutorial of using fiddler with asp.net MVC 3. I am clicking on links after opening fiddler and getting bad request and page not found.

Regards,
Asif Hameed

Comment: And you do not get that error before opening Fiddler?

Comment: actually, I want to  learn how to use fiddler with asp.net MVC 3

Comment: Fiddler is just the web debugging tool. It monitors http connections and shows it to you. I haven't heard of anything like using fiddler with asp.net mvc - you just turn it on and it should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out glimpse. Among other things, it also helps you debug the callbacks: 
http://getglimpse.com/

Answer (score 1):

There shouldn't be any specific setup you need to do to use Fiddler with MVC, however, Fiddler won't show you what action methods are being called.  Check out the previously mentioned Glimpse for that.  Since Fiddler works on the client side (browser), it is monitoring your traffic between your web browser and the web server.  It should just work and show you all the requests.

Each web browser has debugging tools that can also show you a portion of the information that Fiddler does, as well.  You usually find these on the Net tab, and they are invaluable in building Ajax apps.